# How can I specify the dip-pixels in a code?

Tags: android, css

I read that there is two kinds of referent pixels - w3c reference pixel and dip pixel. I do not understand how can I use the dip pixels. Do I have to write, for example, "width:100dip" or something like that. How can I specify this dip-pixels in my html+css+javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

In XML:

`android:layout_width="100dp"`

In Java:

```
int width = dpToPx(100);

public static int dpToPx(int dpWidth) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float screenDpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    int screenPxWidth  = Math.round((screenDpWidth) * displayMetrics.density);
    int dpPxWidth = Math.round(screenPxWidth / screenDPWidth);
    return dpPxWidth * dpWidth;
}
```